# When to use Test="F" or Test="Chisq" when comparing regression models?

Tags: r, regression

I would like to understand when to use either the `test="F"` or `test="Chisq"` options when comparing regression models with the ANOVA function.

In my class, we have been using `test="Chisq"` on all logistic regression problems but now I have a case that is linear regression. When I try comparing the two tests with `test="Chisq"` I no longer get a test statistic.

Do I understand correctly that I need to use `test="Chisq"` for logistic regression and `test="F"` for linear regression?

I am comparing two models now (both linear regression models) and the output of the anova test where `test="Chisq"` only provides `res.df`, RSS, Df, Sum of Sq, and `Pr(>Chi`).

Does this mean I need to do `test="F"` when I don't see a **test statistic**?